# How to mapped my query for recieving the data?

Tags: java, spring, jpql, projection

*I send a Get Postman request and i am receiving status 200. The problem is that I don't get any data about it, it gives me only : [] .
Probably my error is that I don't map the constructor for the DTO class I made.
As another option I guess I have to make a projection or something similar to this, can anyone explain to me how to map the constructor and give me the data I want? I'm so messed up and dealing with this error for 2 hours and nothing.*

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface ManagementRepository extends JpaRepository<Management,Long>,ManagementRepositoryCustom {

    @Query(value = "SELECT wm.action_description " +
            "FROM testdb.warehouse_management wm " +
            "WHERE wm.action_description = :action_description ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<StockRecoveryDTO> findByDog(@Param("action_description") String action_description);

}
```

**DTO:**

```
package com.example.dto;


public class StockRecoveryDTO {

    private Long id_product;
    private String date;
    private int quantity_product;
    private String action_description;
    private Long id_action;
    private String quantity;


    public StockRecoveryDTO() {

    }

    public StockRecoveryDTO(Long id_product, String date, int quantity_product, String action_description, Long id_action, String quantity) {
        this.id_product = id_product;
        this.date = date;
        this.quantity_product = quantity_product;
        this.action_description = action_description;
        this.id_action = id_action;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
//GETTER SETTER
```

**Console:**

```
Hibernate: SELECT wm.action_description FROM testdb.warehouse_management wm WHERE wm.action_description = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

That native query you are return only `action_description` so change the return type to `List<String>`.